# Multi-line TextBox - Paste text with numbered list, bullet list, tab character

Tags: asp.net

How can I make a textbox be a multiline but also allow users to paste text with numbered list, bullet list, and tab character into the editable area without losing the numbers, bullets, and indentation. I don't need any css style.

Answer (score 0):

Any textarea allows entry of HTML.  If you are using ASP.NET, you have to turn off validation of requests which prevents the server from posting back.  If you want users to see the HTML they are posting, then you do need a rich text editor like [TinyMCE](http://www.tinymce.com/) or some other rich text utility (which there are plenty).

Comment: is it possible to do it with the normal textbox?

Comment: The same equivalent of TinyMCE?  No.